# how to add int value from array to NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

**Here is my code**

I'm looping through the array and adding to the `NSNumber`.

```
NSNumber *totalValue = 0; 
NSMutableArray *items = [10, 35, 25]; // Just for demo
for (int i=0; i < items.count; i++)
{
    totalValue = totalValue + [items objectAtIndex:i] // How do I add the totalValue?
}
```

Can someone help me with this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSNumber` is an Objective-C class. Unlike in C++, operators cannot be overloaded in Objective-C so you have to call everything manually.

```
NSNumber *totalValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
for(…) {
  totalValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[totalValue intValue] + [[items objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
}
```

You might want to use `NSInteger` instead, which is faster (especially for a large number of items: memory allocation is expensive):

```
NSInteger totalValueInteger = 0; // no pointer, NSInteger is a POD!
for (…) {
  totalValueInteger += [[items objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
}
NSNumber *totalValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalValueInteger];
```

---

You should really only use `NSNumber` when you *need* an Objective-C object, like in an array, dictionary or coder. Otherwise, use a POD like `NSInteger`, `int` or `double`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can probably do this entire thing using KVC:

```
NSNumber *total = [items valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.integerValue"];
```

But to answer your original question, `NSNumber` is immutable which means you can't change it or increment its value. Creating a new `NSNumber` on each iteration of your loop is inefficient and wasteful.

You should use a standard `int` or `NSInteger` to sum up the total, and then convert the resulting value to an `NSNumber` at the end if you need it like that.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this, while more succint/expressive, will be slower to execute.

Comment: Try it in Instruments. Then decide whether performance is important in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well make the intermediate an int.

```
int temp = 0;
for(…) {
  temp += [[items objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}
NSNumber *totalValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:temp];
```